# Can I send players to different Bedrock edition servers?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I'm using vanilla Minecraft Bedrock server software, and I want to send players from my server, to a different server. However, I'm not sure how to accomplish this, if it's even possible at all.

Is it possible to send players from one server to another? Does anyone have any ideas on how to? Is there different software or plugins I have to use?

Answer (score 1):

Many moons ago there was a `/transferserver` command which I believe would perform in the way you want but this has long been since removed.

By default, there is no way to transfer an individual player to another server and as there is no native "plugin" support for Bedrock Edition servers that route is also an unfortunate dead end.

Being able to perform this action would be quite a potent security risk which could result in players being sent to servers they don't want to be sent to and given how secure Microsoft have been regarding online play I do not imagine there is a valid solution to this problem.

One rather technical solution did however come to mind although without building such a system there would be no way of telling:

It would require sending specific DNS responses to clients so that they think the URL, such as `mc.hypixel.net`, then maps to a different IP address, such as `192.168.1.0`, which could be the IP address of the new server. This would however require a huge amount of technical knowledge and access to all the servers you want to send players to along with dedicated Minecraft servers running on each of those.

If the servers you are sending players to are not yours then there would be no way of doing this. Perhaps a list on a website or other simpler solution would fit your needs however.